# Can Windows 7 Task scheduler start a playlist in Windows Media Player 11?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

I want to run a short list of wmv 's at certain times during each day for a week

Comment: Have you tried it (as in launching the playlist via Task Scheduler)?

Comment: No.  Question arises from a project now in planning stages.  Don't have hardware and software in place to try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes!

1. Create a new "Basic task" in Task Scheduler.
2. Give it a name, time, etc in the wizard that pops up.
3. Tell it to start a program.
4. In "program/script" box type or browse to:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe
   ```

   (will just be `\Program Files\` on x86 system, but thats the path on x64)
5. In "Add Arguments" put `/play /close "C:\Path\To\Playlist.wpl"`

That will launch Media player, automatically play that playlist, then close media player when it's done!

Comment: nice alarm clock!

Comment: Moab: Could be used that way.

Comment: ...any way to specify fullscreen, for running video?