# "/fullscreen" argument does not work when launching Windows Media Player as part of a scheduled task with wake from sleep

Tags: windows-7, sleep, windows-media-player, windows-task-scheduler, fullscreen

I recently asked a question about using Windows 7 Task Scheduler to wake a computer from Sleep mode and play a video, [Windows Task Scheduler to wake from sleep and play a video](https://superuser.com/questions/632541/windows-task-scheduler-to-wake-from-sleep-and-play-a-video), and I got it to work, but the command line argument "/fullscreen" fails to make the video run in full-screen mode.

I did watch the launching and it looks like it might be going into full-screen mode and then immediately going back to windowed mode for some reason, before actually playing the video or within the first split-second of the video.  Maybe that is a clue as to what is happening.

Does anyone know how to get this to work properly?

Answer (score -1):

Is there any particular reason why you need to use WMP? In my experience, it's often easier to use a different player if you need command-line control. One such example is [MPC-HC](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: -1 This does not address the OP's issue. While I agree that WMP isn't the most powerful software, your answer is more like a comment than a real solution

Comment: I really don't want to have to install a new program when I have one that seems like it should be able to do what I want.  I do also use VLC, so I will try launching *that* in fullscreen if I can't get it to work with WMP.  It may be that the fullscreen launch problem extends to *all* media players (or all programs) anyway though, so a solution for WMP might carry over to other players.  In the end, though, what I really want is a solution for WMP so that I can most easily set this up on arbitrary Windows system.

Comment: Yes there is a particular reason. Its called [Play-To](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/using-the-play-to-feature-to-stream-media), which allows your computer to act as a renderer destination for media plus allows your media to 'Play To' other renderers/media extenders on your network. Also, you forgot to include the important reasons for picking MPC-HC given the existence of VLC.

Comment: @AmitNaidu Play To is for playing media on a different screen, so I don't see how it is relevant to the OP's question? I mentioned MPC-HC because it has similar command-line parameters to WMP. Besides, MPC-HC was mentioned just as an example. VLC is another such example.